# How can I get rid of the CORS error when using vue-socket-io

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

Yet another CORS problem. I'm using the vue-socket-io package. I tried many solutions, but none seems to help me.

**node server**

```
var http = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000"));
```

**vue socket io**

```
...
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'

Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: 'http://localhost:3000',
  vuex: {
     store,
     actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
     mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
  }
}));

new Vue({
   router,
   store,
   vuetify,
   render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bF6k.png)

Comment: It may help :- https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#CORS-handling

Answer (score 0):

Try setting options like this. From what I found online there are a couple ways to configure CORS when attaching it to an existing server - and this approach is a different way of doing it.

```
const http = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors:true,
    origins: ['http://localhost:8080'],
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000"));
```

There also appears to be a discrepancy in your screenshot.. It says the origin is `http://localhost:8080` but the CORS header is `http://localhost:8080/` with a `/` at the end.

I'm not certain, but perhaps this could be causing the issue.

Comment: Sadly the same error. I somehow managed to get around CORS (by using Vue's proxy option) and afterwards got 400 bad request, but everything should be named correctly.

Comment: I just noticed in your screenshot there is a discrepancy. It says the origin is `http://localhost:8080` but the CORS header is `http://localhost:8080/` with a `/` at the end. I wonder if this could be causing your issue? Does it work if you use a wildcard CORS like `*`?

Comment: I tried many combinations and I forgot to take a picture from the latest origin. If I use the `*`, I just get the error not to use any kind of a wildcard.